# Small circuit analysis, DC voltage source short circuit or ground?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, small-signal

To convert a BJT into a short circuit we know that all DC voltage sources are short circuited.

Yet my professor did this:

[image]

[image]

Isn't this a contradiction? I just can't grasp the step.

Comment: What contradiction?

Comment: I'm not sure about a contradiction. Perhaps you may add some words to help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction.

> we know that all dc voltage sources are short circuited

No. For a small-signal analysis, all *independent, large-signal* sources (such as the supply rails and \$V_{DC,in}\$) are nulled, and when we null a *voltage* source, we replace it with a short circuit. The point of this is to consider the large-signal and small-signal behaviors separately.

After nulling the large-signal sources of a linearized model, we are ready to compute the small-signal output. If desired, we then combine it with the large-signal output using superposition to obtain final estimated voltages and currents.

\$v_{in}\$ is a small-signal input, and we wish to solve for its small-signal effect on the output. Nulling it would be counterproductive since then you'd have a circuit with no independent sources and you'd just get a bunch of zeros and no meaningful findings.

Likewise, \$g_mv_{BE}\$ is a *dependent* voltage source and is a crucial part of the small-signal model. If you neglect it, you neglect the most important active behavior of the transistor.

Notationally, I find that many textbooks and authors use lowercase variables for these small-signal sources but capital letters for large-signal/operating-point sources, and your example appears to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> To convert a BJT into a short circuit we know that all DC voltage sources are short circuited.

This statement doesn't make sense. The BJT is not being converted into a short circuit.

Your professor is performing a standard ac analysis at the dc operating point of the emitter follower. The mathematical technique is called linearizing to the operating point.

The dc operating voltages are set to 0V, because their values do not change as the ac voltages and currents change. This reduces clutter in the ac analysis..

I personally avoid using "short circuit" if possible. I think it is a phrase that distracts from the true intention. The phrase "set to 0" is better.